# text-align / align-content doesnt work

Tags: css, text-align

I've been trying and trying to get this to work. But no matter what I try, I can't get this to show up in the center.

I searched stackoverflow. I tried margin: 0 auto; and tried removing floating elements. But nothing seems to work.

I must be missing something simple. I'm not very knowledgeable about CSS. Could you please point it out?

```css
body {
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(images/marble.gif);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#about {
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 700px;
}
#about img {
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: black thick solid;
  border-top: black thick solid;
  border-left: black thick solid;
  border-bottom: black thick solid;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin: 3px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
#myPicture p {
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
#myName p {
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24pt;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="about">
  <div id="myPicture">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>
      <img src="images/profile2.jpg" />
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="myName">
    <p>Dude</p>
  </div>

  <div id="myTitles">
    <div class="myTitleClass">
      <p>...
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: To me it's totally in center in snippet, even here in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nk8Lch8t/ so high chances, some other css properties over writing the center css,

Comment: What are you viewing it on? It might be a particular browser/device issue if you aren't seeing it centred.

Comment: The snippet does center the text and image. Also, `align-content: center` doesn't work this way and can be removed. [It's used with `display: flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @Shehary look at the snippet fullscreen and it doesn't align center

Comment: @RachelGallen, yeah I noticed, Thanks,

Comment: Everyone, Thank you so much. You are all great. Stackoverflow is the best thing that happened to developers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have centered the image and the text inside `div#about` which is 700px wide, but the `div#about` itself is not centered. I added `background-color: orange;` to the div, so you can see what's happening here:

[image]

All you have to do is add `margin: 0 auto;` to `div#about` and you'll get this:

[image]

It's centered now. You can get rid of orange background.
Also I've shorten your CSS, check this:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#about {
  width: 700px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#about img {
  border: black thick solid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 3px;
}
#myPicture p {
  text-align: center;
}
#myName p {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24pt;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="about">
    
  <div id="myPicture">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>
      <img src="images/profile2.jpg" />
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="myName">
    <p>Dude</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Wow you are the best! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

ADd margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto to your about section

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8dLrkzz/)

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(images/marble.gif);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#about {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 700px;
}
#about img {
  text-align: center;
  border-right: black thick solid;
  border-top: black thick solid;
  border-left: black thick solid;
  border-bottom: black thick solid;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin: 3px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
#myPicture p {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
#myName p {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24pt;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="about">
    <div id="myPicture">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>
        <img src="images/profile2.jpg" />
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="myName">
      <p>Dude</p>
    </div>

    <div id="myTitles">
      <div class="myTitleClass">
        <p>...
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @user2487896 you have enough reputation to upvote - use it. you should upvote all your answers.